# Segmentation fault in linked list creation

Tags: c

I wrote the following program to create a singly linked list. However it gives a segmentation fault at line 28:  ptr->info =x; The program gets terminated here after inputting the first node of the linked list.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};

struct node *ptr,*start,*prev;
int n,x,i;

printf("enter the number of linked list elements\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
ptr=malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
prev=malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
start=malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
ptr=NULL;
start=NULL;
prev=NULL;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("enter the element\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&x);
    ptr->info =x;
    ptr->link =NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        prev=ptr;
        start=ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->link = ptr;
        prev=ptr;
    }
}

ptr = start;
while(ptr != NULL)
{
    printf("%d ",ptr->info);
    ptr = ptr->link;
}
return 0;
}
```

What is the problem in the code?

Comment: What did you find out when you ran it under your debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are confused w/ the implementation. Why would you declare size for *ptr to be

```
    n * sizeof(struct node)
```

If n is the no. of elements in LL, declare each one inside the loop as:

```
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

and then initialize.

Answer (score 1):

```
ptr=malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
```

This should be inside this for loop-

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    //your code
 }
```

Because every time you add a new node you have to allocate memory to create one.

And also I would suggest you to remove `'\n'` from

```
scanf("%d\n",&x);
          ^Remove this.
```

As it makes your next `scanf` in iteration to be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code is problematic :

```
ptr=malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
prev=malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
start=malloc(n*sizeof(struct node));
ptr=NULL;
start=NULL;
prev=NULL;
```

bottom line you are allocating memory 3 times and when you do you keep a pointer to the memory that was just allocated.
But then you assign that pointer to NULL already and as such you create a memory leak because the memory you allocated is no longer accessible by you.

You most allocate a piece of memory in the loop, for a single item during each iteration and fit it in the  double linked list. The fact that you start by initializing helper pointers to NULL is a good thing. But the fact that you do this initialization after you allocated memory shows you don't quite understand pointers all that good yet.

Comment: Yes thanks, I corrected it. I infact allocated memory for only one pointer in the whole program and it works fine.